# Is “reading a book” a pleonasm?

Tags: phrase-usage, pleonasms

I always see people writing this, and I interpret the “book” as any form of literature – therefore, it should be a pleonasm.

Or do we interpret the “book” as one of the many forms of literature (i.e., a book is different from a magazine, a letter) and it’s therefore correct to specify.

Comment: Have you tried looking "book" up in a dictionary or Wikipedia, if you're unclear what a book is?

Comment: A book is certainly different from a newspaper. And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_signal), 'Polybius, a Greek historian, devised a ... complex system of alphabetical smoke signals around 150 BCE'.

Answer (score 4):

"Reading" is the act of deciphering writing. Which form this writing takes - books, brochures - even writings on a toilet wall - is of no concern. Now, the last one is hardly covered by the term "book", however broad a meaning you assign to it.

Having said this, I'd not qualify "reading a book" as pleonasm at all and consider "book" to mean a certain kind or written artefact among many others - as you yourself suggested.